# pgr_drivingdistance seems to miss a few lines

Tags: postgis, pgrouting

For multiple stations I am running a pgr_drivingdistance function. Its nearly correct but it has a strange behaviour I can not place.

The function seems to leave out some of the road segments around a station. Leaving it with the agg_cost value of null. Then when the station next to it runs through the model it updates the costs that are near another station with a value that is based on the distance towards that station.

I prepare the roadnet with the following code:

```
    select pgr_createTopology('bikenet', 0.000001, 'geom', 'gid')
```

I loop the stations through the following code:

```
    SELECT
         *
    FROM
         pgr_drivingDistance('
         SELECT
            gid as id, source, target, time as cost
         FROM
            bikenet', LOOPEDFILLINSOURCE,
         10000::float, FALSE)
```

Any idea what is causing this behaviour and how to fix it? In underneath picture you can see the result with road segments labelled with agg_cost.

[image: road segments labelled with agg_cost]

[image: not processed roads]

In the second image the red lines show the roads that are not processed at all. So the green dot is the starting point. The black lines are processed and the red ones are not.

Comment: What is your spatial reference system? I see that you have a tolerance of 0.00001. At the equator, and assuming 4326, this is about 11cm.

Comment: I am using 3857